# Switch frame if iframe has same name and id in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have frame where id and name is same and I want to switch the frame. How can I do this?

This what I tried:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe");
driver.switchTo().frame("clntcap_frame");
driver.switchTo().frame("//iframe[@id='clntcap_frame']");
```

HTML code

```
<iframe name="clntcap_frame" id="clntcap_frame" style="" xpath="1"></iframe>
```

In console:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id iframe

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the `iframe` is present in the DOM. If it is present then followings should work l.

Try this:
In this method, you try to pass the frame element itself.

```
    //To check the element exists or not but avoiding any exception, find all the elements with the id and put them in a list. Since id is a unique identifier, it should return only one.
    List<WebElement> frame = driver.findElements(By.id("clntcap_frame"));


   //Then check if the list of elements is empty or not. If not, then the frame is present in the DOM
    if(!frame.isEmpty()) {

        //Since frame is a list we need to get the element in the index 0
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame.get(0));
    } else {
            System.out.println("Frame with this id doesn't exists");
        }
```

Comment: This what I got    :  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[@id='clntcap_frame']"}

Comment: Ho do I check if It is in DOM or not? I don't know this please reply

Comment: @Preeti updated the code. check now.

Comment: This has worked for me :       new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("frame_name")));